# Are there a way to block a program from starting during certain times?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I want to prevent a certain program from being started during specific times. Are there a good way of accomplishing this at *nix distros?

Comment: My only idea is to create cron jobs that make chmod -x at the beggining and +x at the end of your time period.

Comment: It depends what you need to prevent from starting it.

Comment: I want to prevent a logged in user at an Ubuntu workstation from starting certain programmes

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the user obtains a copy of the executable and tries to run it? What if the user gets the source code and compiles the program?

Comment: No idea, but I know that it won't be Linus Torvalds who will be using the computer of which I need to apply this blocking at, so I am pretty sure that no compiling will occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `crontab` rigged to create or remove a file in `/var/lock/`, and have the program test for the existence of that file. If the file exists, refuse to run.

Note that this will not keep a determined and intelligent user from simply copying over the program and altering it to ignore the test -- but then again, using a `cron`-scheduled `chmod -x/+x` won't deter smart users either...

Answer (score 0):

A cron job to chmod the files to add/remove the execute permission could do this (as pbm's comment suggests).

Alternatively you could put all these apps (assuming its a small set of well-defined apps) in one directory, and then rename (or remove permissions on the directory) in a cron job.

Alternatively, you could setup SELinux (or other Linux security solutions?) to whitelist/blacklist applications.  I didn't see anything that easily accomplishes from some quick googling, though.